# i have problem with recursive function with pointer input

Tags: c++, pointers, recursion

So I'm trying to make an function to fill 1 matrix in spiral order
it kinda look like this

```
1 2 3
8 9 4
7 6 5
```

i'm trying to fill the outside first then use same kind of recursive function to fill no smaller inside but i only got 1 inside :

```
1 2 3 4
12 1 1 5
11 1 1 6
10 9 8 7
```

here the code that i use

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
void spiral_making(int sr,int sc,int er,int ec,int counter,vector< vector<int>>*so1){
    
    //sr :starting row
    //sc : stating column
    //er : ending row
    //ec : ending column
    int i; //iterator
    //insert the first row into the matrix
    if((sr-er==1)||(sc-ec==1)){(*so1)[sr][sc]= counter;}
    {
    for(i=sc;i<ec;i++){
        (*so1)[sr][i]=counter;
        counter++;  
    }
    
    //increse the starting row  by 1 
    sr++;
    //insert the back
    for (i=sr;i<er;i++){
        (*so1)[i][ec-1]=counter;
        counter++;
    }
    //then I reduced the ending column by 1
    //insert the bottom row (but it will be back ward) 

    ec--;
    for(i=ec;i>sc;i--){
        (*so1)[er-1][i-1]=counter;
        counter++;
    }
    //then i insert the left size column(but it also go backward)
    for(i=er-1;i>sr;i--){
        (*so1)[i-1][sc]=counter;
        counter++;
    }
    //then I icrease starting column and decrease ending row
    er--;
    sc++;
    //check if there are any small matrix inside if yes then conduct this function again with the smaller matrix
    if((er<sr)&&(sc<ec)){
        spiral_making(sr,sc,er,ec,counter,&(*so1));
    }
    }
}
int main(){
    
    //input section
    int n;
    do{
        std::cout<<"please input the  number greater than 1: ";
        cin>>n;
    }
    while(n<0);
    //try to work out with the matrix 
    vector< vector<int> > so(n,vector<int>(n,1));
    spiral_making(0,0,n,n,1,&so);
    //print the output
    for (int u=0;u<n;u++){
        for(int y=0;y<n;y++){
            std::cout<<so[u][y]<<" ";
        }
        std::cout<<std::endl;

    }
    return 0;
    

}
```

i'm kinda new so spare me for this stupid question:)))

Comment: `&(*so1)` can simply be `so1`.

Comment: The condition `er<sr` is likely false on the first call, and so the recursive call is never made. Did you mean this comparison the other way round?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to do it with `std::array` instead. Maybe you could adapt it to your need.

```
template <size_t N>
using squareArr = std::array<std::array<int, N>, N>;

template <size_t N>
void spiral(squareArr<N>& mat) {
    if (mat.empty()) return;

    // Counter 
    size_t cnt{0};

    // Limits of the current circle
    size_t top{0}, left{0}, right{mat[0].size()-1}, bottom{mat.size()-1};

    while (top < bottom && left < right) {
        // Assign clockwise in the outer circle
        for (auto i=left,    j=top;    i<=right;  i++) mat.at(j).at(i) = cnt++;
        for (auto i=right,   j=top+1;  j<=bottom; j++) mat.at(j).at(i) = cnt++;
        for (auto i=right-1, j=bottom; i>left;    i--) mat.at(j).at(i) = cnt++;
        for (auto i=left,    j=bottom; j> top;    j--) mat.at(j).at(i) = cnt++;

        // Get a smaller circle
        top++, left++, right--, bottom--;
    }

    // Center (if N is odd)
    if (top == bottom && left == right) {
        mat[left][top] = cnt++;
    }
}
```

Testable [here](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlJvoCqAZ0wAFAB4gA5AAYppAFZdSrZrVDIApACYAQjt2kR7ZATx1KmWugDCqVgFcAtrRABWAMykr6ADJ5aTAA5ZwAjTGIQADZSAAdUIUJzWjtHFy4ADjiEpLp/QJCncMivY0xTZIYCZmICVOdXTyNMEzM6KpqCfOCwiOijatr69M4soUGugJ6ivo8ASiNUB2JkDikdDwDkRywAak0PGxriZgBPA%2BxNGQBBDa2dzH3D83HiTGYnC6vb7U3abYcewONleAWAXxu3wImCcsVU0KeILwAC9MAB9Ai7IIQ64ORLqXZCACODhqmGuxGITwAIoSCOgQCBjmdgeMGUzKSznvRSFiLrzsR5Lh59JCbtDYfDHqyUejMYLLjcAG6oPDoXaxYgBAgQNC0caEklkinEYEKnRRXZOZgEOb7ADsotuMgAnDQqRBmA4iBbdqwpiArTa7ZpHd8ri6I%2B7dhBtbtaM5A/7AiGw2LI66I2zGWhvYjgfHnPnDrswFJS%2BsReHM5n7dTqxmXdmUEtMcCC2XNG4bLRO1X06H65C69XrhK4TbpYdEqiMXyhd8VWrCbE8CdWBBiaS3iazV9tJbrbaHU6I3gqDGjwA6GGxAinCBzO1vAjLWgHU/pgD0X92dgc9ARPs6YznKuzIPQoa6DIg4fqOEY/rs/hOIQQi7KgF4EAgjzIMsbz0OBa7bJgDagXORCxFBMF1ry7BUAQVGDryWrAAgDGOkeXbQV21JXqBj4ALScExuyhKgBBEJ8HE2nxsqCcJI79s6zougA7ggeDsDGFGIqJ4mSfsB6%2BnRbYlixbGpp%2BjaIdcQiJMAtDgawqDIAA1qpeAiLsAS7FhjytkByBEewDZRiQMZekQ3kHNSJm8rsCUKDFFEfglCV4O2HjUuZDEiulBgGHa142hAChzFeJV4CGWXgZBegFUpEZhR6kWoNFWU5fFuxJVlKV6MJeXdZl1JiRJqCfHlSX1XoRUySVZUVTqVU0rVDHTfojU1m64Wet6bUZR1eCsQQQm8j1I36eNqUHdgJmpWleACQJs0EItpXlZV1W0hBa36PVm2NtGu1RQdsWYPRXVDVlo2SalPXYL5qCUYNiVPS9b0LZ9K0/QV/2fipCG/gA4pgmLMIS1qsOwVJBSsIUDq6fV/YYfrg79BjMUdbFPbyMPjU9cEDiOYoqYhNhWNCHrnli3loRg6BzA20sQDpMUxXpY1OIZUTGWzNLqzllmha6nFuLod1uPWZspZb2N1czgsE8LtzO1Ct5SoiZGYgwOJLuq6AnKpDCruuACyJVGyBRo7pSwI%2B0KQa5VZQgh2wEBHorAOatq6fBo7Wb0jmrbFjYdLsj4rD567NxxtaASPuGaYqQHzBB6nrDh7lNgDdgDcAy3bdrmwnfAtoFx91ZA/B0PHc2sCHjj5nk%2BB9PYdz4c3CL/nrpT%2B3I%2BHG4W/9yve/r93MFChPDa7zP%2B82Nom%2BX0vo5pbsL5vrsF%2Bns7UgLKw0huHkK4WQ8hUDSBsLjXQhIlgrGlL8Tg8gCDSDkE%2BUgrl3AZCvDIe0owXRuG4A/DIHgohRBkG4FQ0huBAOQaA6Q8ghAgBkKQJBICFhwFgEgTA4hyh7TIBQT0xBgBCFEGoFoDAECoFUsAhBpA0Cwk0jaZIIjAisHEZI4BchZHjVXNTEAwBOAGK0fI6mAB5b0aipE0O8Nw5AFIhF0OseUKo%2BBgHyH4IwFg7AuC8HccIMQkgQGKGUKodQKBIEqDwKEBhkAFhIzaPqaQAk2QxS0OtTg9p6EwNWMoNkARlFiIkZYqQMjVInFiDQv%2BADqGBLAVIcQGQogCSiNwXYwBkDIF2AYq8nBdjYBsbwmMuBCDhQ2JwO0ED1qIIqQsdB3BOBXhdNoDInAZDcDcPaNwnAogeF4P/KQVDSAaNoVIehjDmHTIoVIbQ1TNG1KmawhYSoIiJAsNwIAA%3D)